# plotly histogram subplot size

Tags: python, plotly, histogram, subplot

I want to create 20 subplots histogram charts with ploty but the size of the overall plot is not optimal:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objs as go

data = [some data]
fig = make_subplots(rows=len(data), cols=1, shared_xaxes=True,
                    vertical_spacing=0.02, row_heights=[50] * 20)
p = 1                   
for i in data:
    fig.append_trace(go.Histogram(x=i), row=p, col=1)
    p += 1
    
fig.show()
```

The plot looks like this:

[image]

I would like to have some more space between the plots and increase the height of the subplots. I tried to play with the vertical_spacing and row_heights parameters but the plots are not updating.

How can I increase the height of the subplots and the space between them?

Comment: In this case, this spacing can be adjusted after extending the size of the original graph. Currently the default size is fixed, which is the reason. e.g.`fig.update_layout(autosize=False,height=1000,width=800)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with @r-beginners, you'll have to play with the size options to get the plots to look right. There are two ways I've used before, setting the size in `fig.update_layout()` or when exporting the image in `fig.write_image()`.

updating image:

```
fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=1920,
    height=2000)
```

exporting image:

```
fig.write_image('histograms.pdf',
    width=1920, 
    height=2000)
```